# Default Multiple Metadata values in list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, managed-metadata, managed-metadata-column

Is there a way, for a column in the SharePoint list having the `metadata` type, allowed `multivalue`, to add a default value having multiple metadata entries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add multiple entries as default value for managed metadata column in SharePoint.

Go to column settings > Default value and click on this icon/image:

[image]

Then you can select multiple default entries like this:

[image]

---

**OR**

Directly type multiple entries in Default value textbox like:

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

While creating a new managed metadata column, first time set only one default value. Then again edit column settings and set two default values.

Comment: when I select the second value, it removes the first one

Comment: Did you check/select "Allow multiple values" checkbox?

Comment: While creating a new column, first set only one default value. Then again edit column settings and try to set two default values.

Comment: Yes, I did check multiple values, save it, returned back... I have the "classic list experience"

Comment: First setting a simple value; saving, and then returning and pasting the multiple values as text seem to work... It looks like a MS bug, please add to your answer the "first" trick ;)

Comment: Updated the answer.